# amsmath "\substack"-command in section title

Tags: beamer, sectioning, amsmath

I do use the `\substack`-command in text for creating a small (2,1)-Vector. Unfortunately it does not work in the title of a section.

Here a minimal example, which does not work:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\section{$\substack{ a\\b }$}
\end{document}
```

To my surprise it works, if I use `\section*` instead of `\section`.
I am far from understanding enough about TeX to tell why this happens, but can anyone give me an advise how I can fix it?

PS: I also tried to substitute `\substack` by `smallmatrix`, which did work for the first two times I compiled the file. After the third compilation I got the same problems.

EDIT:
The Problem was solved, using the `\protect`-command. But now I want to use the same sectiontitle for a beamer presentation, using the `beamer`-class. Also using the `\protect`-command I receive an error. How can I solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: @PeterGrill (and @Greyfox) A `\protect` will help: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Oh yeah, really should try harder to not forget about `\protect`ion. :-)

Comment: Amazing. It works. You are a wizard. :-) Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Greyfox -- your edit may not be noticed by many readers.  it's better to enter a new question, pointing back to this one.

Comment: @Werner Thx to you and barbara for teaching me the basics. I will do as you told me, if the answer of Andrew Swann fails. But I do think, his answer is great and I can finish this threat as soon as I got to my computer and tried it. Next time I will do better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\substack` is what is known as a fragile command in LaTex and needs protecting in situations like section titles and captions that get written to external files for producing tables of contents etc.  See [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/15925) for some more information on fragile commands.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{$\protect\substack{ a\\b }$}

\end{document}
```

If you have the `hyperref` package loaded then you will also need to provide a plain text version, via

```
\section{\texorpdfstring{$\protect\substack{ a\\b }$}{a/b}}
```

Finally, if using the `beamer` class there is an extra problem with `\\` which beamer redefines.  One work around in this case is to define a custom command to be used in the title:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\myfr}{\texorpdfstring{$\substack{a\\b}$}{a/b}}

\begin{document}

\section{\myfr}

\begin{frame}
  Test.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Notice here that you can make the command robust from the start.

[image: Beamer sample]

Comment: Thx, for this Extension. Using the `\textorpdfstring`-command, I can now solve all my problems.