# Figure as superscript in section title

Tags: graphics, sectioning, superscripts, sections-paragraphs

I would like to have a section title of special type: I need it to be a letter with a figure in superscript. My code (that does not work) would be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[slovak]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{palatino,verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}
\section{$\Sigma_1^{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image-a}}$}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: otherwise the standard trick of using `\section[stuff for the toc, no unprotected fragiles]{actual section heading}` will work....

Comment: @cmhughes Can you, please, give some simple example of what you suggested? Thanks.

Comment: see, for example, [amsmath "\substack"-command in section title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100746), [Footnote in sub-section title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153329), [Using \total of totcount package in section title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53536), and lots more :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either `\protect` the command from expanding via

```
\protect\includegraphics[..]{...}
```

or [make it robust](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764) using something like [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,etoolbox}
\robustify{\includegraphics}
\begin{document}
\section{$\Sigma_1^{\includegraphics[scale=0.05]{example-image-a}}$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, both work very well. Can you, please, explain, what does the `\protect` command do?

Comment: @Suzie: You should read [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/5764) Specific to your case, the argument of `\section` is considered to be a "moving argument" as it not only winds up in the text where you place it, but also possibly in the ToC. As such, it is written to file where full expansion is attempted *unless* you `\protect` (or `\robustify`) it. Also see [David's comment on this topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43127/error-with-newcommand-and-section/43129#comment88023_43129).