# Insert matrix into \subsection{}?

Tags: sectioning, matrices

I was trying to insert matrix into a \subsection{}:

```
\subsection{Suppose $X= \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{array}$}
```

This gives me an error:

```
 ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Try `\subsection[]{Suppose $X...` It compiles for me. Note `[]` which is supposed to hold the short content.

Comment: Related: [`amsmath` `\substack`-command in section title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100746/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want `smallmatrix` rather than `array`. But you can also use the full size version, if you really want.

The key is that `\begin`, `\end` and `\\` are fragile so they need `\protect` in front of them when in a moving argument (section title or caption).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Suppose $X=\left[\protect\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 2 \protect\\
3 & 4
\protect\end{smallmatrix}\right]$}

\subsection{Suppose $X=\protect\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \protect\\
3 & 4
\protect\end{bmatrix}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you need the matrix to show up in the table of contents, as well, here is one technique:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\savestack{\mathexpr}{$X= \bracketMatrixstack{1 & 2 \\3 & 4}$}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Main Topic}
\subsection{Suppose \mathexpr}
\section{Next Topic}
\end{document}
```

[image]